# Min and Max labels positioning

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

i would like to know to define the min and max labels at position "start" or "inside"
and the others labels between this two at center position,

i'm using ChartJS 4.2.1

What i'm currently trying

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        position: 'top',
        grid: {
          display: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },

        ticks: {
          color: 'blue',
          maxRotation: 0,
          min: {
            position: 'start',
          },
          max:{
            position: "start"
          }
        },
      },
      y: {
        reverse: true,
        grid: { display: true, drawOnChartArea: false },
      },
    },

    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      labels: {
        position: 'right',
      },
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The min and amx options of axis can accept the values to have a user min and max.
But you can set the align option to the ticks to "inner". In this way the min and max are aligned to left (min) and to the right (max) of chart area.

```
scales: {
  x: {
    position: 'top',
    grid: {
      display: true,
      drawOnChartArea: false,
    },

    ticks: {
      color: 'blue',
      align: 'inner', // <-- to add, removing min and max setting
      maxRotation: 0,
    },
  },
  y: {
    reverse: true,
    grid: { display: true, drawOnChartArea: false },
  },
},
```

Comment: Thank you it does resolve the main problem ! 
Do you know the correct ways to adjust the width of the ticks font / size ?

Because with this solution indeed the Min and Max ticks do stay inside from the Axis but they are overlapping on the closiest Ticks ..

Comment: The font option is "scriptable" (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options) therefore you can use a function (1 argument, the context type "tick) where you can set the font you want for each tick.